# Perl hashref/property confusion

Tags: perl, properties, hashref

Ignoring the fact that this probably wouldn't happen if one was using strict and warnings, I'd like to know why these two cases differ.

```
#!/usr/local/perl5/bin/perl

$x[0] = "";
$y[0] = "";

$x[0]->{name} = "SRV";
$y[0]->{name} = "FINAL";
print "$x[0]->{name}, $y[0]->{name}\n";

$x[1]->{name} = "SRV";
$y[1]->{name} = "FINAL";
print "$x[1]->{name}, $y[1]->{name}\n";
```

Output is:

```
FINAL, FINAL
SRV, FINAL
```

Why, when the index is zero, does the y[0]->{name} assignment affect x[0]->{name}, but not when the index is one?

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: It doesn't do that for me.

Comment: Likewise: @Sean: can you check again and demonstrate this behaving the way you see it behave. On unix, you could use: `cat test.pl && perl test.pl`

Comment: You're right.  I removed two initial assignments in my code I thought weren't necessary to show the issue.  This is now exactly the code I'm running.  Perl -v reports that it's version v5.8.4.

Answer (score 5):

That's not the code you actually ran. In the code you presented, `$x[0]` and `$y[0]` are references to different hashes, but in the problematic code, `$x[0]` and `$y[0]` are references to the same hash. Like in the following code:

```
my %hash = { name => "SRV" };
$x[0] = \%hash;           # $x[0] is a reference to %hash.
$y[0] = $x[0];            # $y[0] is a reference to %hash.
$y[0]->{name} = "FINAL";  # Changes $hash{name}.

print $x[0]->{name};      # Prints $hash{name}.
print $y[0]->{name};      # Prints $hash{name}.
```

The above problem can be fixed by changing

```
$y[0] = $x[0];
```

to

```
$y[0] = { %{ $x[0] } };
```

or

```
use Storable qw( dclone );
$y[0] = dclone( $x[0] );
```

Comment: Okay, so in the edited version of the code I had assigned both $x[0] and $y[0] to null (well, really, "").  So, what you're saying is that since both were assigned to null, they were each a reference to the same hash, so they were essentially the same variable.  However, $x[1] and $y[1], since they were not assigned to anything, were not references to the same variable.  (I'm not trying to get them to be the same.  This came up because one was modifying the other and causing an issue in a script.)

Comment: @Sean, Always `use strict; use warnings;` You're telling Perl to access a hash whose name is the empty string.  In the `[1]` examples, they are truly <strike>null</strike> undef, so Perl creates a hash for you when you need one in the dereferences. (This is called autovivification.)